# Why date formatter crashes?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

My below code is working fine.
I don't know why it crashes sometimes(Mostly on application launch. 1 case out of ~100).

```
extension Formatter {
    static let enUSPOSIX: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")//
        return formatter
    }()
}


let dateFormatter = Formatter.enUSPOSIX
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+hh:mm"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2018-05-13T00:00:00+05:30")
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
let calendar = Calendar.current
let dayComponent = calendar.component(.year, from: date!)//crashes here sometime
print(dayComponent)
```

Comment: I recommend to look up https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns.  `+hh:mm` is *not* the correct pattern for a time zone.

Comment: @MartinR: Nice catch, but can you please explain why it only crash sometimes, not all of times.

Comment: @QuocNguyen: Actually the provided example does *not* crash in my test, because `+05:30` matches `+hh:mm` (05 happens to be a valid hour in the 1-12 hour format). It would for example crash for `-05:30` or `+13:00`  because these do not match the pattern.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for explain. The priovided example doesn't not crash in my test, too :D

Comment: @MartinR thanks. is `TimeZone(identifier` should be `TimeZone(abbreviation` ?

Comment: @MartinR when i use `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"` it crashes(somtimes)  please help :(

Answer (score 1):

Basically your date format is wrong. The time zone `+05:30` is `ZZZZZ` not `+hh:mm`, please read [unicode.org Date Format Patterns](https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Pattern_Examples)

```
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
```

**Edit:**

For this standard ISO8601 format I'd prefer `ISO8601DateFormatter`

```
let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2018-05-13T00:00:00+05:30")
```

Comment: Sorry please explain how to decide `ZZZZZ` ?

Comment: @ameyrane From the mentioned documentation: *The ISO8601 extended format with hours, minutes and optional seconds fields. The ISO8601 UTC indicator "Z" is used when local time offset is 0*

Comment: @Rob i think `+0530` is for `X` not `+05:30` ?

Comment: When i use `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"` it crashes(somtimes)  please help :(

Comment: What dates do crash?

Comment: `"2018-09-13T00:00:00+05:30"` @vadian

Answer (score 1):

Today I met exactly the same problem. Application randomly crashes on production because of force unwrapping on `open func date(from string: String) -> Date?`

My code looked like this:

```
let creationDate: Date = {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    return dateFormatter.date(from: "19-06-2018 14:00")!
}()
```

After my investigation I realized that crashes appear only on devices which have set 12h date format in device settings. In these cases `14:00` does not exist because it should be "2:00PM".

Simply change in code fix that problem:

```
let creationDate: Date = {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

    return dateFormatter.date(from: "19-06-2018 14:00")!
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when testing on one of my applications

```
let dateFormatter = Formatter.enUSPOSIX
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+hh:mm"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2018-05-13T00:00:00+05:30")
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
let calendar = Calendar.current
let dayComponent = calendar.component(.year, from: date!)
```

This is Crashing because the date object is nil so when fore unwrapping the date in dayComponent line this crashes. try this

```
let dateFormatter = Formatter.enUSPOSIX
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+hh:mm"
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2018-05-13T00:00:00+05:30"){
   dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
   let calendar = Calendar.current
   let dayComponent = calendar.component(.year, from: date!)
}else{
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss+hh:mm" // Date as 12 hour  
 if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2018-05-13T00:00:00+05:30"){
   dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
  let calendar = Calendar.current
  let dayComponent = calendar.component(.year, from: date!)
} else{
   print("Cannot format Date")
 }
}
```